# Removing sound of Youtube Video in Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, api, youtube

I use the Youtube API for Actionscript 3 to dynamically load Youtube videos.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html#Loading

When I remove the current video using player.destroy(); and stage.removeChild(), the video goes away. But when the newly loaded video beginning, the sound track from the previous video plays in the background.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem when using the FLVPlayback component. This is how I solved it:

```
SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

Ran that before I played a new video.

Of course remember to:

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
```

Comment: I run into the same problem before. Unfortunately SoundMixer only works for FLVPlayback component. Turns out I was reference the wrong object. player.stopVideo() + loader.loadURLRequest() work fine. For more info visit this page: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html